# Фильтр значений LDAP

Tags: golang

Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой, нужно отсеивать значения LDAP которые не являются текстом, проверял через **unicode.IsPrint()**, и она отлавливала почти все некорректные значения, но например такие она почему-то пропускает как валидные

```
+ j â t y  ÷ J © ù ×  à + É
```

вот эта=же строка в Unicode

```
43 106 226 116 121 136 247 74 169 249 215 146 224 43 201 159
```

Подскажите какое-нибудь надёжное решение для валидации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут дело не в печатных значениях, а в том что сама строка это невалидный UTF и при проверках неправильный символы заменяются на rune(65533).

```
func IsPrintString(s string) bool {
    barr := []byte(s)
    for len(barr) > 0 {
        r, rlen := utf8.DecodeRune(barr)
        if !unicode.IsPrint(r) {
            return false
        }
        if !utf8.Valid(barr[:rlen]) {
            return false
        }
        barr = barr[rlen:]
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает как надо, единственное я сократил ф-цию в if до  !unicode.IsPrint(r) || !utf8.Valid(barr[:rlen]

Comment: И ещё вопросик, а utf8.ValidString() не то-же самое сделает? просто с ней можно даже ф-цию не городить.

Comment: И нельзя ли заменить всю ф-цию на utf8.Valid()